# Process.GetProcesses Memory Leak

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, process

I'm using `Process.GetProcesses()` to get all running process on local machine but i'm having a issue with memory leak, I guess.

That's the code which retrieve my process list:

```
List<Process> allProcess = Process.GetProcesses().Where((process) =>
{
    try
    {
        return process.GetMainModuleFileName().Contains("NAME") && !Native.IsResponding(process);
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}).ToList();
```

Extension GetModuleFileName (returns file path independent of architecture)

```
public static string GetMainModuleFileName(this Process process, int buffer = 1024)
{
    var fileNameBuilder = new StringBuilder(buffer);
    uint bufferLength = (uint)fileNameBuilder.Capacity + 1;
    return QueryFullProcessImageName(process.Handle, 0, fileNameBuilder, ref bufferLength) ?
        fileNameBuilder.ToString() :
        null;
}
```

IsResponding function

```
public static bool IsResponding(Process process)
{
    HandleRef handleRef = new HandleRef(process, process.MainWindowHandle);
    int timeout = 2000;

    IntPtr lResult = SendMessageTimeout(
        handleRef,
        0,
        IntPtr.Zero,
        IntPtr.Zero,
        SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG,
        timeout,
        out IntPtr lpdwResult);

    return lResult != IntPtr.Zero;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(
    HandleRef hWnd, 
    int msg, 
    IntPtr wParam, 
    IntPtr lParam, 
    int flags, 
    int timeout, 
    out IntPtr pdwResult);
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
private static extern bool QueryFullProcessImageName([In] IntPtr hProcess, [In] uint dwFlags, [Out] StringBuilder lpExeName, [In, Out] ref uint lpdwSize);
```

When my `allProcess` are filled with any result my application memory grows a little and never decrease. I already tried:

```
for(int i = allProcess.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    allProcess[i].Dispose();
    allProcess[i] = null;
}

allProcess = null;

GC.Collect();
Native.CloseSharedResources();


public static void CloseSharedResources()
{
    PerformanceCounterPermission performanceCounterPermission = new PerformanceCounterPermission(PerformanceCounterPermissionAccess.Read, ".", "*");
    performanceCounterPermission.Demand();
}
```

Just for test, when I remove the `Process.GetProcesses()` the memory stay stable. 
Why the memory never decrease?

Comment: Does QueryFullProcessImageName fail and if it does can you call GetLastError and include the error codes?

Comment: What does `Native.IsResponding` do?

Comment: @rene works fine. No error in this function. I will edit with the `Native.IsResponding`

Comment: So QueryFullProcessImageName never returns false?

Comment: Instead of HandleRef use SafeHandle

Comment: @rene SafeHandle it's a abstract class. I will see how implement. `QueryFullProcessImageName` throws when don't have access by security giving me Access danied,

Comment: @KevinKouketsu any chances to share entire code that is possible to build and run? the case seems to be interesting I want to check it in Deleaker.